# Using an Amazon API Gateway with ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have created AWS Lambda functions that I need to travel from client to amazon web services via encrption. The only way I saw to do this from the amazon docs is by setting up an api gateway.  I deploy it and get this sample as an endpoint:

```
https://my-api-id.execute-api.region-id.amazonaws.com/test/mydemoresourc
```

To access this is the only way to do it like so:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://portkey.formspring.me/login/"];

//initialize a request from url
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[url       standardizedURL]];

//set http method
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
//initialize a post data

NSDictionary *postDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"username", @"username",
                          @"password", @"password", nil];

NSError *error=nil;

NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:postDict
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted     error:&error];



[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

//set post data of request
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

//initialize a connection from request
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

//start the connection
[connection start];
```

Or does the aws ios sdk have a different way to do it in the docs or samples somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is also an efficient way to call the AWS Lambda function but there is one way too in which you can use Amazon Cognito service.

See this link for further knowledge :

[Building a Mobile Backend Using AWS Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/getting-started-lambda.html)

[Execute Code On Demand with Amazon Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/lambda.html)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I originally wanted to use that but I want the data from client (iphone) to systems (aws) to be encrypted. Is there a way to use above with SSL/encryption?

Comment: Did you mean effient or inefficient?

Comment: AWS API Gateway is an EFFICIENT way to that. If you want to apply SSLs to your API gateway calls then this a solution to that

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html

Comment: Will this work for ios apps? If I don't do a client side cert then even tho my api is at https://api-url then my data from the client to the backend is not encrypted?